# Sonatype Nexus holding tar and war artifact with same maven coordinates not listed in the lucene search api

Tags: java, maven, jenkins, nexus, sonatype

I am using Sonatype Nexus V2.14.4 as my artifact repository. We use the lucene search end point to pull the list of versions available on Nexus.

```
http://nexusurl/service/local/lucene/search?a=abc&repositoryId=releases
```

We have scenario where a project publishes 2 artifacts with the same artifactid/groupid/version but different types, war and tar.gz. While I do a search using the above url, war file is not listed.

```
<searchNGResponse>
<totalCount>5</totalCount>
<from>-1</from>
<count>-1</count>
<tooManyResults>false</tooManyResults>
<collapsed>false</collapsed>
<repoDetails>
<org.sonatype.nexus.rest.model.NexusNGRepositoryDetail>
<repositoryId>releases</repositoryId>
<repositoryName>Releases</repositoryName>
<repositoryContentClass>maven2</repositoryContentClass>
<repositoryKind>hosted</repositoryKind>
<repositoryPolicy>RELEASE</repositoryPolicy>
<repositoryURL>
http://nexusurl/service/local/repositories/releases
</repositoryURL>
</org.sonatype.nexus.rest.model.NexusNGRepositoryDetail>
</repoDetails>
<data>
<artifact>
<groupId>com.abc</groupId>
<artifactId>abc</artifactId>
<version>10.2.1</version>
<latestRelease>10.2.1</latestRelease>
<latestReleaseRepositoryId>releases</latestReleaseRepositoryId>
<artifactHits>
<artifactHit>
<repositoryId>releases</repositoryId>
<artifactLinks>
<artifactLink>
<extension>pom</extension>
</artifactLink>
<artifactLink>
<extension>tar.gz</extension>
</artifactLink>
</artifactLinks>
</artifactHit>
</artifactHits>
</artifact>
<artifact>
<groupId>com.abc</groupId>
<artifactId>abc</artifactId>
<version>2.1</version>
<latestRelease>10.2.1</latestRelease>
<latestReleaseRepositoryId>releases</latestReleaseRepositoryId>
<artifactHits>
<artifactHit>
<repositoryId>releases</repositoryId>
<artifactLinks>
<artifactLink>
<extension>pom</extension>
</artifactLink>
<artifactLink>
<extension>tar.gz</extension>
</artifactLink>
</artifactLinks>
</artifactHit>
</artifactHits>
</artifact>
<artifact>
<groupId>com.abc</groupId>
<artifactId>abc</artifactId>
<version>1.2</version>
<latestRelease>10.2.1</latestRelease>
<latestReleaseRepositoryId>releases</latestReleaseRepositoryId>
<artifactHits>
<artifactHit>
<repositoryId>releases</repositoryId>
<artifactLinks>
<artifactLink>
<extension>pom</extension>
</artifactLink>
<artifactLink>
<extension>tar.gz</extension>
</artifactLink>
</artifactLinks>
</artifactHit>
</artifactHits>
</artifact>
<artifact>
<groupId>com.abc</groupId>
<artifactId>abc</artifactId>
<version>1.1</version>
<latestRelease>10.2.1</latestRelease>
<latestReleaseRepositoryId>releases</latestReleaseRepositoryId>
<artifactHits>
<artifactHit>
<repositoryId>releases</repositoryId>
<artifactLinks>
<artifactLink>
<extension>pom</extension>
</artifactLink>
<artifactLink>
<extension>tar.gz</extension>
</artifactLink>
</artifactLinks>
</artifactHit>
</artifactHits>
</artifact>
<artifact>
<groupId>com.abc</groupId>
<artifactId>abc</artifactId>
<version>1.0</version>
<latestRelease>10.2.1</latestRelease>
<latestReleaseRepositoryId>releases</latestReleaseRepositoryId>
<artifactHits>
<artifactHit>
<repositoryId>releases</repositoryId>
<artifactLinks>
<artifactLink>
<extension>pom</extension>
</artifactLink>
<artifactLink>
<extension>tar.gz</extension>
</artifactLink>
</artifactLinks>
</artifactHit>
</artifactHits>
</artifact>
</data>
</searchNGResponse>
```

Is this a bug with nexus search api?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See here:

https://support.sonatype.com/hc/en-us/articles/213464708-Why-does-search-not-find-artifacts-within-the-same-GAV-but-with-different-extensions-

Note that the above limitation is for Nexus 2.x.  Nexus 3.x does not have this limitation.